# Почему не заходит в условие?

Tags: c++

```
#pragma once

#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class Deque{

    struct Data{
        Data* next;
        Data* previous;
        T info;
    };

public:

    Deque(){
        this->right = nullptr;
        this->left = nullptr;
    }

    void push_back(T element){
        Data* ref = new Data{
            nullptr,
            right,
            std::move(element)
        };


        if(this->left == nullptr && this->right == nullptr){
            this->left == ref;
        }else{
            this->right->next = ref;
        }

        this->right = ref;
    }

    T pop_back(){
        T t = std::move(this->right->info);
        Data* ref = this->right;
        this->right = this->right->previous;
        this->right->next = nullptr;
        delete ref;
        return t;
    }

private:

    Data* left;
    Data* right;

};
```

Почему в методе `push_back` не выполняется условие:

```
if(this->left == nullptr && this->right == nullptr)
```

В самом начале, когда я добавляю первый элемент в контейнер, поля `left` и `right` инициализированы `nullptr`. Но условие все равно не проходит.

Comment: Вы отладчиком видите, что условие не выполняется?

Comment: Если нет отладчика, можно расставить `std::cout << "blah blah\n"` и посмотерть в какую ветку условия идет выполнение программы.

Comment: я пользовался отладчиком, он просто пропускает весь блок if/else. Поле left остается null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

это причина

```
this->left == ref;
```

компилятор просто пропускает эту строку

нужно было написать

```
this->left = ref;
```